# How did "invoice" end up with an 's'-sound?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, french, pronunciation-vs-spelling

The Etymonline entry for *invoice* states ([source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=invoice)):

> apparently from M.Fr. *envois*, pl. of *envoi* "dispatch (of goods),"

Although my French is pretty poor, my understanding is that the 's' is silent. We don't pronounce the 's' in *hors d'oeuvre* (usually), so how did the 's' in *envois* become vocalized?

Two ideas that come to mind are that 1) people read the spelling without knowing the proper pronunciation and it caught on, or 2) a "rule-maker" decided the 's' shouldn't be silent (and turned it into a 'c'). If the latter is the case, are there some other examples of this?

Comment: Hello Zairja, as far as I know and FWIW, I would not say "usually" because "hors d'oeuvre" is used as way of referring to the preliminary course, while "hors d'ouevres" is used for delicace served with cocktails.

Comment: That *-s* wasn't always silent.

Comment: @StoneyB Which one? And is there a link I can follow?

Comment: French final 's'. I'm afraid I'm no scholar of OF, but I dimly remember from my historical linguistics class back at the dawn of time that that sound sort of drifted away over the course of several hundred years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED takes a whack at explaining this as follows:

> Etymology: app. orig. = *invoyes*, pl. of *invoy*, corresp. to 16th c. Fr. *envoy* (now *envoi*), f. *envoyer* to send: cf. Fr. *lettre d’envoi* letter of consignment, invoice.
>
> Inferentially, this derivation is satisfactory, both as to meaning and form. *In‑*  from Fr. and earlier Eng. *en‑*  is usual; and the writing of  *‑ce* for the plural  *‑s* is found in other words, as *dice, mice, pence,* in some of which also, as *accidence, bodice, dace, truce,* the resulting form is treated as a singular. But the historical record is not complete: the examples of *invoy, invoyes,* are scanty and not very early, and an earlier *envoy* in this sense is not exemplified.

So it seems that we do in fact get  *‑ce* words from things that were originally  *‑s* words.  However, in this case it sounds like they aren’t entirely convinced of the matter, either — which puts you in fine standing if I do say so myself. :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! An OED subscription is looking more and more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

As the French spelling suggests: the s was originally pronounced.  French spelling has a lot of 'ghosts' of former pronunciations in the same way that English does.